# Zipkin Combining Spans

Tags: zipkin

I am new to Zipkin and am trying to understand how to view all spans in a trace.

On the trace query page for Zipkin I am seeing a trace come through with the expected 5 spans. The problem is that when I click "SHOW" to view the individual spans, it only shows 3 spans (and now says it only has 3). There should be two spans for both the API-GATEWAY and the CURRENCY-CONVERSION services, but they seem to be combined for some reason.

**Query Page:** Note it says 5 spans here
[image]

**Trace Page:** Note it now says there are only 3 spans
[image]

I am using the stock Docker image openzipkin/zipkin:2.23 with the sampler probability set to 100% for all services. Is there some configuration that I am missing? I would really like to be able to see the timing breakdown of the individual calls.